# Recipients field of MFMessageComposeViewController doesn't show in iOS 7

Tags: ios7, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

The code below works fine in iOS 5/6. In iOS 7, it looks like this (red oval for emphasis).

[image]

Code:

```
if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
    self.messageComposer = [MFMessageComposeViewController new];
    self.messageComposer.recipients = @[number];
    self.messageComposer.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:self.messageComposer
                       animated:YES
                     completion:nil];
}
```

**Question**: This is simple code. Is there some other external property, perhaps of the presenting view controller, that is affecting this? Anyone have a fix or workaround?

thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've found that the MFMessageComposeViewController's recipient field seems to take some of it's appearance from the UINavigationBar appearance proxy in iOS7. To work around this, I've done the following in my apps:

1. Create an empty custom UINavigationController subclass, which doesn't override any of UINavigationController's methods.
2. Use this custom UINavigationController subclass as a marker for any navigation controllers that I want to have custom appearance, by setting the custom class on the identity inspector in IB:

   [image]
3. In my app delegate, set up the appearance of navigation bars like this:

   ```
    [[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MyCustomNavigationController class], nil] ...];
   ```

This ensures that I get the navigation bar appearance I want in the controllers I want to customize, but preserves the standard navigation bar (and related) appearance in other controllers (like MFMessageComposeViewController). Here's a screenshot; note the standard appearance of MFMessageComposeViewController, with the custom navigation bar appearance on the popover in the background:

[image]

Comment: That was easy. thanks. I'm already using a subclass for `UINavigationBar` so I changed my appearance settings to only apply to this navbar class `i.e. [MyNavBar appearance]`. This also solves the problem.

Comment: Fantastic write up and solution - and really easy to implement too!

Answer (score 20):

I faced same problem and here is my solution-

Before presenting your message composer( `[self presentViewController:messageComposer animated:YES completion:nil];` )
 set

`[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`

and in delegate method

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller
                 didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result {
     UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Navigation Bar"];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Thats all!!

Comment: This works as a quick and easy work around - just make sure to add the [UINavigationBar appearance] code snippet before you init/alloc the MFMessageComposeViewController