# Apple's controllers not presenting properly in iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

In my iOS app i present standerd controllers MFMessageComposeViewController and UIImagePickerController.

But they both presenting with strange navigation bar.

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can i fix this problem?

**UPD** code for presenting controllers

UIImagePickerController:

```
UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    cameraUI.sourceType = sourceType;
    cameraUI.allowsEditing = YES;
    cameraUI.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:cameraUI animated:YES completion:nil];
```

MFMessageComposeViewController:

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *messageViewController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
        messageViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        messageViewController.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        recipient= [NSStringMask maskString:recipient withPattern:@"\\+(\\d{1}) \\((\\d{3})\\) (\\d{3})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{2})"];
        messageViewController.recipients = @[recipient];
        messageViewController.body = body;
        [self presentViewController:messageViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is strange about it? Have you read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/

Comment: @Popeye, you can see strange lines on bars. and in MFMessage table with bubbles not sizing in all view

Comment: It's not a strange navBar. It's just that since the new statusBar is transluscent the view start at the top of the screen (and not 20).
And Im sure that the grey line is a view with a frame like that : `(0, 40, 320, 1)`

Comment: @KIDdAe ok, i add `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];` before  calling this controllers. but still not working

Comment: I believe `KiDdAe` is correct that the line is the top of the initial view for that view controller. You need to have the `y` position start 20 pixels further down the screen if on iOS7 device.

Comment: @Popeye i understand it. but how? could you give me sample code. i can't change view's frame, because this is not my controller

Comment: Please provide code for how you are currently doing your thing.

Comment: @Popeye see it un update. But it is really basic way to do it

Comment: Can you not just do something simple like `[[cameraUI view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];` obviously replacing the `0`s with your dimensions and do the same for `messageViewController` or try doing `mashdup`s answer if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105591/recipients-field-of-mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller-doesnt-show-in-ios-7?rq=1). I used the second answer, though I suspect the first would work for me also.

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 7, the status bar and the navigation is translucent by default. To make the view act 'normal' like in iOS 6. you need to add this to the controller you are presenting.

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

If you want to read up more about changes in views. Check out this post. I find it a nice quick overview whats changed.

http://www.brianjcoleman.com/ios7-weve-got-a-problem/

Comment: that's sound good for customs controllers. but i use Apple's controllers. I try to inherit from UIImagePickerController. Add this code, but nothing change.

Comment: you can put it when you create the instance. so replace self with cameraUI. so if([cameraUI respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)]) cameraUI.edgesForExtendedLayout = UITectEdgeNone;

Comment: nothing help. maybe something in plist?? or.. i don't know ((